# How to extract value from json in scala

Tags: json, scala

I have this elasticsearch SearchResponse in json format and I want to extract the value to a float object in scala

```
response: org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse = {
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 819,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "food_bowl" : {
      "value" : 6358.6576502407115
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I did but don't seem to get it right.

```
val getJson = parse(SearchResponse)
  val getElement = getJson
  for (myValue <- getElement) {
    val ValueResult = myValue.extract("value")
```

Comment: So any luck with finding the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following dependencies added or present in the project:

```
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-core" % "3.5.3",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.5.3"
```

We import required library methods:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, _}
```

and define the data itself:

```
val json =
    """
      |{
      |  "took" : 3,
      |  "timed_out" : false,
      |  "_shards" : {
      |    "total" : 5,
      |    "successful" : 5,
      |    "failed" : 0
      |  },
      |  "hits" : {
      |    "total" : 819,
      |    "max_score" : 0.0,
      |    "hits" : [ ]
      |  },
      |  "aggregations" : {
      |    "food_bowl" : {
      |      "value" : 6358.6576502407115
      |    }
      |  }
      |}
    """.stripMargin
```

After that we extract raw value wrapped in `Option`:

```
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

  val rawValue = parse(json) \ "aggregations" \ "food_bowl" \ "value" toOption
```

and pattern match it for target float type:

```
  rawValue match {
    case Some(JDouble(float)) => println(float)
    case _ => println("Value not present in JSON")
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

After parsing the json, you can extract it as a float

```
scala> import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse
scala> import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
scala>   implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
formats: org.json4s.DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats$@4d529dbf
scala> val parsedFloat = (parse(json) \ "aggregations" \ "food_bowl" \ "value").extract[Float]
parsedFloat: Float = 6358.6577
```

Comment: Am getting error   scala> import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse
<console>:7: error: object json4s is not a member of package org
       import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse
                  ^

scala> import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
<console>:7: error: object json4s is not a member of package org
       import org.json4s.DefaultFormats

Comment: You need to add dependencies to use Jackson library. "org.json4s" %% "json4s-core" % "3.5.3",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.5.3" I have computed it on spark-shell where there is no need to add.

Comment: I see, but am using lift web framework can anyone help on how to use lift-json to achieve that. Thanks

Comment: You may refer from here https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to respond, I have done this but not working.
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  case class GetValue ( value: Double)
println(parse(rawJson3).extract[GetValue].value)